# Dynamic Html.ActionLink parameters with Areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I'm having a problem generating dynamic links to items from my code.

Code that I'm using:

```
Html.ActionLink("View Checklist Summary", "Details", "Product", 
     new { Area = "Reporting" }, new { Item = 478})
```

What I need:
**URL -- localhost:58412/Reporting/Product/Details?Item=478**

What I'm getting:
**URL -- localhost:58412/Reporting/Product/Details**

I've been working on this for way too long, and I can't seem to find any reason why the "Item=478" is not being added to the URL created by the ActionLink.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
Html.ActionLink("View Checklist Summary", "Details", "Product", new { Area = "Reporting", Item = 478 }, new { })
```

The Area and the Item must be specified in the routevalues object. The last empty object, if I recall, is the HtmlAttributes object.

Comment: Ah, That's it exactly. It's one of those things you stare at for too long and drives you nuts!